# How can I reuse function in all the activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

Hello Everyone I'm developing an android app in which I've created function getGPS() in my Activity. Now I wanna use this function everywhere in my app, in all the activities. I've tried by creating another java file but it want works. Can anyone tell me how can I use it?

```
package com.example.hp.mirocareltd;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.location.*;


public class main_page extends AppCompatActivity {
    LocationManager service;
    Intent intent;
    boolean enabled;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page);

        //super.getGPS(); // not working
        // new BaseMethods().getGSP(); // not working 

        Button buttonLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do something in response to button click

            }
        });

    }
}
```

I've created another java file and written following code

```
package com.example.hp.mirocareltd;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;


abstract class BaseMethods extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void getGPS(){
        LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean enabled = service
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // check if enabled and if not send user to the GSP settings
        // Better solution would be to display a dialog and suggesting to
        // go to the settings
        if (!enabled) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Location");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Turn ON your GPS location to Access!");
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            //finish();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It might not be the best way but you can override the Application class, put this method there and access in every Activity via: `((MyApplication) getApplication()).getGPS()`

Comment: @GabrielCosta That would make the code look nasty due to casting. And it's best to keep this kind of code away from the Application class.

Comment: @Jeffrey Even though it would work, I agree that, in terms of readability, this is bad.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how can I call this function?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is quite simple. Create a new abstract class that extends from `AppCompatActivity` (for example, name it: `BaseActivity`). Then, every Activity you add should extend from the `BaseActivity`. Make your `getGPS()` function *protected* and you'll be able to access it from all sub-Activities.

```
abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    protected void getGPS() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your code only one error left main_page.this not enclosing class => AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(main_page.this).create();

Comment: What if it is needed somewhere else than in an activity? I know he didn't specify it but why would an activity have the responsibility in getting a GPS positioning and displaying a view?

Comment: @dipeshmodi Replace `main_page.this` with `this` and the error will go away.

Comment: @PmanAce You're right about it not being the activity's responsibility to handle GPS, but for the sake of simplicity, this does seem like a suitable answer for what the OP is asking.

Comment: @PmanAce well, you do need a Context to get the GPS so, at the very least, you'll need an Activity or Service to be involved.

Comment: @GabrielCosta Dependency injection solves that problem. One can safely pass the application's context.

Comment: Continuing using best practices, it's better to inject your context to the entities that need it than relying on an Activity or Service object, talk about overkill. :)

Comment: Yeah, I know. There's Dagger 2 for that. But, under the hood, my point remains. You'll need, at the very least, an Activity, Service or the Application. You may call it somewhere else due to your architecture but they're still needed. In these cases, I like using Dagger better because it's more scalable and readable than one superclass with a bunch of helper methods.

Comment: What is the error shown? Are you putting your BaseActivity as the superclass of your Activities? Is the method protected?

Comment: @dipeshmodi I really recommend you to learn more about programming in general. You need to understand how inheritance works. Your activity must extend from `BaseActivity` before you can call `getGPS()`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing it the proper way, using dependency injection (something like Dagger2 for example) and create an interface named PositioningService or LocationService to inject into your activity. That service would contain your method getGPS().

This way now you can easily test your getGPS() method and inject that service in any part of your app that needs it. You can even control the lifecycle of your dependency, if it's the same instance every time it is needed or a new instance.

Comment: While this is clearly the better way to go, because it follows design principles, I think this answer is too complicated for the OP. Inheriting this kind of functionality in a base activity class makes more sense, because the OP indicated it will be used throughout the entire app. Meaning the `getGPS()` method can be called from the `BaseActivity` in `onCreate()`, preventing a lot of code duplication.

Comment: While that is true, why not teach him good practices from the get go?

Comment: Because there's no point in teaching something so complicated it will only raise so many more questions than solve the current one. I think it takes years before someone fully understands principles like this. Clearly, the OP has quite a way to go...

Comment: @Jeffrey, I'll give you that, indeed. I even voted for your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

To reuse the function everywhere, create a class utils.java. It should be declared public and final. Then, write all the functions you think you need to reuse everywhere in your app. Make the functions public static.

Here is an example code:

```
public final class utils.java
{

private utils()
{
}

//Here is your function
public static void getGPS() {
        ...
    }

//You can add how many every functions you want
//And use them across your app
public void getSum()
{
}

}
```

You can use these funtions by calling utils.getGps().

Comment: Well, you can't access services in static methods because you need the context. Even if that was allowed, using it may cause memory leaks.

Comment: While this may seem like something easy, you will have a tough time mocking static methods when you unit test. It is better to mock the behaviour of an instance of a class.